# sage : plotting graph with dotted edges

Tags: sagemath

I need to draw a graph in which some edges are usual and some edges are dotted.

I know how to make all the edges dotted (using the option "dotted" for the parameter edge_style of plot). But I need mixed edges (some are dotted and some are usual).

Kindly help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Also asked (and answered) as [Ask Sage question 43872: Creating graph with dotted edges](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/43872).

Comment: See also [Stack Overflow question 55768473: How to color an edge in a graph as a certain color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768473).